# Show Django Admin DateTimeField accordingly to User's timezone

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django I have two models - User and Kiosk

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    role = models.CharField(
        'User Role',
        choices=ROLES,
        default='agent',
        max_length=15)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Updated on', auto_now=True)
    timezone = TimeZoneField(default='America/Los_Angeles')
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True)

class Kiosk(models.Model):
    '''Kiosk unit'''

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=60)
    enabled = models.BooleanField('Enabled', default=True)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Created on', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Updated on', auto_now=True)
    last_check_in = models.DateTimeField('Last Time Checked In', null=True)
```

I need to represent timestamps `created_on, updated_on, last_check_in` in Django Admin accordingly to `timezone` field in User (request.user.timezone).

I thought of creating custom `Widget` but in this case I would need to manually add it to each timestamp field, which doesn't sound right, especially, taking into considerations that I wanted to scale in future adding more models with timestamps.

Is there any more pythonic solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: Your dates won't show up in the first place because you have "auto_now_add = True" which makes those fields uneditable, hence won't be available on Django admin.

Comment: @TechniCollins I included these fields in fieldsets and readonly fields in django admin, so I can see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply your custom `Timezone` based on `request.user.timezone`  one need to:

1. Create middleware in `app/middleware.py`

I basically run `timezone.activate()` if user is not Anonymous with timezone obtained from current user model

```py
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            tzname = request.user.timezone
            timezone.activate(tzname)
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

2. Add it to installed middlewares in `settings.py`

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'app.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware'
]
```

In this example I used `pytz` external python library. My answer is based on official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)